# Defining an operator in Mathematica?

Tags: operators

How to define the following operator in Mathematica?

$$\hat{\nabla}^4=\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\hat{r}^2}+\frac1{\hat{r}}\frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{r}}\right)^2$$

Comment: Is this what you mean? `(Laplacian[u[r], {r,theta}, "Polar"])^2`

Comment: @Nasser I think it should be nested `Laplacian` rather than directive square.

Answer (score 13):

It should be this:

```
lap = D[#, {r, 2}] + 1/r D[#, r] &;
lapsquared = lap @* lap;
lapsquared[f[r]] // Simplify
```

Or using `Laplacian` to define `lap`

```
lap = Laplacian[#, {r, θ}, "Polar"] &;
```

Comment: Wow, never knew of `@*` AKA `Composition`!

Comment: @Ruslan It happens to be it :); also `/*` for `RightComposition`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer:

```
operator[f_] := Nest[(D[#, {r, 2}] + 1/r D[#, r]) &, f, 2]
operator[f[r]]
```